# Some Cloud Functions formats are not deployed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I guess it must be a silly reason but I don't understand why from these 2 Cloud Functions, only the first one is recognized and deployed when I run the following command:

```
firebase deploy --only "functions:test1,functions:test2"
```

The first function that is a simple CRON is well deployed:

```
exports.test1 = functions
  .pubsub.schedule('2,7,12,17,22,27,32,37,42,47,52,57 * * * *')
  .timeZone('Europe/Paris')
  .onRun((context) => {
    console.log('test1');
});
```

The second one that receives data from a PubSub is never deployed:

```
exports.test2 = (message, context) => {
  const name = message.data
    ? Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString()
    : 'World';

  console.log('test2');
};
```

Do I have to use the gcloud commands to deploy the second one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second function `test2` which receives data from Pub/Sub is triggered by a Pub/Sub topic.  Cloud Functions for Firebase with Pub/Sub trigger which you can find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events#trigger_a_pubsub_function). As per the linked documentation you should mention the Cloud Functions for Firebase to be triggered by the Pub/Sub topic inside the functions code. The `firebase deploy` command does not have an option to specify the trigger topic while running the command. So if you want to deploy both the functions at a time then you should change your code to include the trigger topic as following -

```
exports.test2 = functions.pubsub.topic('topic-name').onPublish((message) => {

  const name = message.data
    ? Buffer.from(message.data, 'base64').toString()
    : 'World';
      
  console.log(name);   
  });
```

`topic-name` is your Pub/Sub topic name.

If you don’t want to deploy both the functions at a time, then you can deploy the `test2` function using `gcloud` with the code you have written and specify the trigger topic name while running the command, as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/pubsub#deploying_the_function).